# Obtener un dato en particular de un json desde php

Tags: php, json

como están? Les hago una consulta, tengo el siguiente codigo en php:

```
function getCotizacionDolar(){



$ch = curl_init();

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json', 
    'Authorization: BEARER eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjkxOTAxMzUsInR5cGUiOiJleHRlcm5hbCIsInVzZXIiOiJhbGVqYW5kcm8zMDkwMUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.oJisOihr0r0NA0_30hTiGiG1OiLmESAdF44uiDz60CcStW2IKU8jnD78eAdeC7SF60QCOWuFU_Rd9SFgX0hYkw'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/tasa_badlar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$respuesta = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$resultado = json_decode($respuesta, true);
```

}

Lo que hace básicamente es traerme un json con la cotización del dolar del día, el tema es el siguiente, sólo quiero el último valor de ese archivo json, como puedo pedir el ultimo dato? o como puedo recorrer los 120000 datos que me trae para obtenerlo?
intente recorrerlo con un for, pero no me deja ya que me dice que no es un array. Alguien me diria como puedo hacerlo? a continuacion les dejo lo que me devuelve (solo una parte porque es larguisimo):

> [{"d":"2003-01-02","v":21.75},{"d":"2003-01-03","v":18.375},{"d":"2003-01-06","v":18.1875},{"d":"2003-01-07","v":14.6875},{"d":"2003-01-08","v":13.4375},{"d":"2003-01-09","v":10.5625},{"d":"2003-01-10","v":8.9375},{"d":"2003-01-13","v":13.75},{"d":"2003-01-14","v":11.6875},{"d":"2003-01-15","v":14.3125},{"d":"2003-01-16","v":13.8125},{"d":"2003-01-17","v":13.5},{"d":"2003-01-20","v":14.3125},{"d":"2003-01-21","v":13.8125},{"d":"2003-01-22","v":16.3125},{"d":"2003-01-23","v":12.9375},{"d":"2003-01-24","v":10.5625},{"d":"2003-01-27","v":13.4375},{"d":"2003-01-28","v":12.1875},{"d":"2003-01-29","v":15.375},{"d":"2003-01-30","v":12.9375},{"d":"2003-01-31","v":11.4375},{"d":"2003-02-03","v":13.125},{"d":"2003-02-04","v":15},{"d":"2003-02-05","v":14.5625}]

Comment: No me funciona, me arroja este error: <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Practica_Supervisada\Controlador\ControladorDolar.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />

Comment: Puesto que dices: *como puedo recorrer los 120000 datos que me trae para obtenerlo*  yo te pregunto, ¿por qué transportar inutilmente 120,000 datos? ¿por qué no filtras de forma que obtengas solamente el dato que necesitas? ¿La API la programaste tú? ¿Si no la programaste tú, no tiene una forma de consultarla para que te traiga un dato en específico y no 120,000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es sencillo , la función [curl_exec](http://php.net/manual/es/function.curl-exec.php) retorna `true` o `false` nada más. Es ahí donde está el error.

Lo que se podría hacer para este caso sería añadir la opción `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` para que retorne un `String` con el resultado de la llamada.

A partir de eso, ya puede utilizar  [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php), para luego con [end($array)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.end.php) obtener el último elemento.

**Ejm**

```
$ch = curl_init();

$headers = [
    'Content-Type: application/json', 
    'Authorization: BEARER eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1NjkxOTAxMzUsInR5cGUiOiJleHRlcm5hbCIsInVzZXIiOiJhbGVqYW5kcm8zMDkwMUBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ.oJisOihr0r0NA0_30hTiGiG1OiLmESAdF44uiDz60CcStW2IKU8jnD78eAdeC7SF60QCOWuFU_Rd9SFgX0hYkw'
];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/tasa_badlar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
$respuesta = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$resultado = json_decode($respuesta);
$ultimoelemento =  end($resultado);  
echo $ultimoelemento->d ;
echo $ultimoelemento->v ;
```

Comment: El error es quizá mucho más grave: él dice que está trayendo *¡ 120000 datos !*... Le preguntaría si hay alguna justificación para transportar 120,000 datos para luego elegir una solo. ¿Por qué no se filtra el dato antes de transportarlo?

Comment: @A.Cedano Al parecer la [API](http://estadisticasbcra.com/api/documentacion)  no permite tal filtrado. O al menos en la documentación no está.

Comment: Me parecería increíble que una API no permita filtrado, obligando a transportar miles de datos. Si quien la programó es el OP debería dotarla de esa posibilidad, si es una API de pago el usuario debe exigir esa posibilidad y quien la programó debería quizá dedicarse a otra cosa.

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy de acuerdo, pero más allá de eso mi respuesta no solo le servirá para esos miles de registros si no a a entender por qué no obtenía la respuesta adecuada con curl_exec.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con cedano, el programador es medio bestia, jaja.. trae un historico dia a dia desde el 2003 del valor del dolar, una locura, pero me trae todo ese valor, deci que eso se va a encargar el hosting y no el usuario jaja... Muchas gracias chicos!!! ahi deje como quedo!!

Comment: @GALS no era necesario escribir una respuesta si la respuesta de Dev. Joel contenía en efecto la solución. En cuanto a la ¿API?, tu servidor también se va a cargar, porque está recibiendo una ingente cantidad de datos. Si fuera tú me comunicaría con los responsables de la API o investigaría si no existe otra que funcione mejor. Con lo fácil que sería algo como: `http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/tasa_badlar/today` y que te devuelva sólo la tasa de hoy. O algo como `http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/tasa_badlar/YYYYMMDD` para la tasa de una fecha dada.

Comment: sI, PERDON @A.Cedano, estoy aprendiendo a usar stack y me mareo un poco con el tema de los comentarios y eso. Lo del responsable, bueno, es el banco central de Argentina, asique no creo que den mucho caso jaja... igual voy a seguir averiguando alguna otra api, por ahora es la unica que tengo, encima, ahora son 120k de datos, va aseguir creciendo demasiado y no se va a poder usar. Para colmo tiene restriccion de 100 consultas diarias, asique por algo sera. Pero les agradezco porque aprendi muchisimo!! GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 0):

Joel!!!!! solo modifique un poco el como llamarlo, porque no me funcionaba la ultima parte de ese código. Acá dejo como lo solucione:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.estadisticasbcra.com/tasa_badlar');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true);
$respuesta = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$resultado = json_decode($respuesta, true);
$ultimoelemento =  end($resultado);  

var_dump($ultimoelemento);
$fecha = $ultimoelemento ["d"];
$valorDolar = $ultimoelemento ["v"];
echo $fecha;?><br><?php
echo $valorDolar;
```

Comment: El segundo parámetro `true` de `json_decode` hace que obtenga un array associativo, caso contrario obtendría un objeto. es la única razón ya que en mi respuesta no tengo un segundo parámetro. Saludos y me alegra que haya resuelto su problema. ;)

Comment: Ahhhhhh por eso... claro, lo deje en true... ahora aprendi algo mas... Muchas gracias!!!!